# Why am I seeing DISABLE TRIGGER ALL in this output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I have a slightly unconventional Rails 4.2 application.  There are no migrations associated with the models you see in the below statement(s). Instead to create the database tables, a db/car.sql was used.

But now when I run `bundle exec rspec spec/models` I get the below output.  What is causing this output to appear?  As far as I can tell the schema.rb file looks the same as if I had built it up using *rails migration* generator.  There's a few database indexes but that's it.

**rspec output**

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
   (0.4ms)  ALTER TABLE "kites" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "tails" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "cars" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "car_washes" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "cars_engines" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "cities" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "engines" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "wheels" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "cars_wheels" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL
   (0.4ms)  ALTER TABLE "kites" DISABLE TRIGGER USER;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations" DISABLE TRIGGER USER;ALTER TABLE "tails" DISABLE TRIGGER USER;ALTER TABLE "cars" DISABLE TRIGGER USER;ALTER TABLE "car_washes" DISABLE TRIGGER USER;ALTER TABLE "cars_engines" DISABLE TRIGGER USER;ALTER TABLE "cities" DISABLE TRIGGER USER;ALTER TABLE "engines" DISABLE TRIGGER USER;ALTER TABLE "wheels" DISABLE TRIGGER USER;ALTER TABLE "cars_wheels" DISABLE TRIGGER USER
   (1.0ms)            SELECT schemaname || '.' || tablename
          FROM pg_tables
          WHERE
            tablename !~ '_prt_' AND
            tablename <> 'schema_migrations' AND
            schemaname = ANY (current_schemas(false))

   (0.8ms)  select table_name from information_schema.views where table_schema = 'automobile_test'
   (758.2ms)  TRUNCATE TABLE "public"."kites", "public"."tails", "public"."cars", "public"."car_washes", "public"."cars_engines", "public"."cities", "public"."engines", "public"."wheels", "public"."cars_wheels" RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;
   (0.4ms)  ALTER TABLE "kites" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "tails" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "car_washes" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "cars_engines" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "cities" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "engines" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "cars" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "wheels" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "cars_wheels" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL
   (0.5ms)  ALTER TABLE "kites" ENABLE TRIGGER USER;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations" ENABLE TRIGGER USER;ALTER TABLE "tails" ENABLE TRIGGER USER;ALTER TABLE "car_washes" ENABLE TRIGGER USER;ALTER TABLE "cars_engines" ENABLE TRIGGER USER;ALTER TABLE "cities" ENABLE TRIGGER USER;ALTER TABLE "engines" ENABLE TRIGGER USER;ALTER TABLE "cars" ENABLE TRIGGER USER;ALTER TABLE "wheels" ENABLE TRIGGER USER;ALTER TABLE "cars_wheels" ENABLE TRIGGER USER
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
```